# Authorization from C# with auth2 and linkedin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, authorization, linkedin-api

I have a WebApi that I want to authorize my user with his linkedin information (as in create an access token and inject it in to my owin).

So far I have tried to work with [Sparkle.Linkedin](https://github.com/SparkleNetworks/LinkedInNET) and this is what I have

```
public LinkedInLogic() {
    // create a configuration object
    _config = new LinkedInApiConfiguration(ApiKey, ApiSecret);
    // get the APIs client
    _api = new LinkedInApi(_config);
 }

 public Uri GetAuthUrl() {
     var scope = AuthorizationScope.ReadBasicProfile;
     var state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
     var redirectUrl = "http://localhost:1510/api/login/RedirectAuth";
     return _api.OAuth2.GetAuthorizationUrl(scope, state, redirectUrl);
 }

 public void GetAccessToken(string code) {
     //If I do api.GetAccessToken(code); here I get an access token
     var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1510/api/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + code);
     request.GetResponse(); // my owin authorization
 }
```

So I first get the Authorization Url -> it opens a popup -> I enter my data and it goes back to a controller which fires up `GetAccessToken`.

Problem is even if I completely authorize with linkedin I am not sure how to authorize with my own webapi. So I tried to send an http request to my owin token giver but it doesn't like it. There is also doesn't seem to be anyway I can return the access token back to the user so he can use it in his session.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if the sparkle is working anymore since the changes that where made by Linkedin on May 2015